# System.IO.IOException: error loading native library

Tags: c#, wpf, google-speech-api, dialogflow-es, system-error

I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not sure the way I ask is proper or not.
I modified the code of google speech using WPF from google cloud and then I added the dialogflow into it. It worked well for the first time. But when I reopen the file and try to run for the 2nd time, it says

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was 
not handled in user code

Additional information: Error loading native library E:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\GoogleSpeech\bin\Debug\grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll
```

Help! I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Since it's an I/O exception I'd guess that some DLL (possibly a lot of them) is missing, locked, corrupt, located in a different folder, or has some other problem that is preventing it from being found and loaded. Did you move your project to a different folder?

Comment: I copied the project to another folder cause I want to add some other codes for some new features.

Comment: Open your project files and change any references to e:\ to a relative path, using ..\.. if needed.

Comment: I just tried your method and it works quite good now.Thanks!